# Kendo UI grid export to Excel using template values

Tags: javascript, excel, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have tried to follow [the example](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/excel/column-template-export) but this does not work for me. I have:

```
function invoicedJobsGrid() {
        var invoicedJobsDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            serverPaging: true,
            pageSize: 25,
            requestEnd: function (e) {
                if (e.type == 'read') {
                    $('.today-count').html(e.response.counts.today);
                    $('.week-count').html(e.response.counts.week);
                    $('.month-count').html(e.response.counts.month);
                    // document.title = 'Invoiced jobs (' + (e.response.counts.currencies.GBP + e.response.counts.currencies.USD + e.response.counts.currencies.EUR) + ')';
                }
            },
            sort: {
                field: "invoice_id",
                dir: "desc"
            },
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: 'invoiced-list',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST'
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(e.errorThrown + "\n" + e.status + "\n" + e.xhr.responseText);
            },
            filter: [{
                field: 'invoice_date',
                operator: 'gte',
                value: $('.month-count').parent().data('period')

            }],
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                total: 'total',
                model: {
                    id: 'id',
                    fields: {
                        invoice_id: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        entity_id: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        job_id: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        invoice_date: {
                            type: 'date'
                        },
                        invoiceDate: {
                            type: 'date'
                        },
                        jobType: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        customer_name: {
                            type: 'string'
                        },
                        termId: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        account_number: {
                            type: 'string'
                        },
                        firstName: {
                            type: 'string'
                        },
                        sales_area_id: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        margin: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        sales_total: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        sales_total_gdp: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        job_costs_value_pounds: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        vat_native: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        buying_parts_value_pounds: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        buying_fees_value_pounds: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        shipping_value_pounds: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        symbol: {
                            type: 'string'
                        },
                        margin_percent: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        zone_name: {
                            type: 'string'
                        },
                        zone_id: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        buying_total: {
                            type: 'number'
                        },
                        emailed_date: {
                            type: 'date'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            aggregate: [
                {field: "buying_total", aggregate: "sum"},
                {field: "buying_total", aggregate: "average"},
                {field: "shipping_value_pounds", aggregate: "sum"},
                {field: "shipping_value_pounds", aggregate: "average"},
                {field: "job_costs_value_pounds", aggregate: "sum"},
                {field: "job_costs_value_pounds", aggregate: "average"},
                {field: "buying_fees_value_pounds", aggregate: "sum"},
                {field: "buying_fees_value_pounds", aggregate: "average"},
                {field: "buying_parts_value_pounds", aggregate: "sum"},
                {field: "buying_parts_value_pounds", aggregate: "average"},
                {field: "sales_total", aggregate: "sum"},
                {field: "sales_total", aggregate: "average"},
                {field: "margin", aggregate: "sum"},
                {field: "margin", aggregate: "average"},
                {field: "sales_total_gdp", aggregate: "sum"},
                {field: "sales_total_gdp", aggregate: "average"},
                {field: "vat_native", aggregate: "sum"},
                {field: "vat_native", aggregate: "average"},
            ]
        })

        var invoicedJobsGrid = $('#invoicedJobsGrid').kendoGrid({
            toolbar: ["excel"],
            excel: {
                allPages: true
            },
            excelExport: function(e) {
                var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];
                var template = kendo.template(this.columns[6].template);

                for (var i = 1; i < sheet.rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = sheet.rows[i];

                    var dataItem = {
                        zone_name: row.cells[5].value
                    };
                    row.cells[5].value = template(dataItem);
                    console.log(row.cells[5])
                }
            },
            dataSource: invoicedJobsDS,
            autoBind: true,
            height: 680,
            editable: false,
            pageable: {
                pageSizes: [25, 50, 'All'],
                messages: {
                    display: '{0} - {1} of {2} invoiced jobs',
                    empty: 'There are no invoiced jobs',
                    itemsPerPage: 'invoiced jobs per page'
                }
            },
            dataBound: function (e) {
                var grid = e.sender;
                if (grid.dataSource.total() == 0) {
                    var colCount = grid.columns.length;
                    $(e.sender.wrapper)
                        .find('.k-grid-content tbody')
                        .append('<tr class="kendo-data-row no-results-row"><td colspan="' + colCount + '" class="no-data">No invoiced jobs for current filters</td></tr>');
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    title: 'Account #',
                    field: 'accountNumber',
                    width: '100px',
                    template: '#=accountNumber ? accountNumber : "<i class=\\"fa fa-pencil create-account-number\\"></i>"#'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Customer',
                    field: 'name',
                    template: '<a href="/laravel/entity/#=entity_id#" target="_blank">#=name#</a>'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Date',
                    field: 'invoice_date',
                    width: '85px',
                    template: '<abbr title="#=kendo.toString(invoice_date, "dd/MM/yyyy at HH:mm")#">#=kendo.toString(invoice_date, "dd/MM/yyyy")#</abbr>'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Invoice',
                    field: 'invoice_id',
                    width: '80px',
                    template: '<a href="/laravel/invoice/#=enquiry_id#" target="_blank">#=invoice_id#</a>'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Job',
                    field: 'job_id',
                    width: '65px',
                    template: '<a href="/laravel/activity/#=enquiry_id#" target="_blank">#=job_id#</a>'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Trdr',
                    headerTemplate: '<abbr title="Trader">Trdr</abbr>',
                    field: 'traderId',
                    width: '90px',
                    template: '<abbr title="#=full_name#">#=trader#</abbr>',
                    filterable: {
                        ui: gridFunctions.traderFilterUI,
                        extra: false
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Zone',
                    field: 'zone_id',
                    filterable: {
                        ui: gridFunctions.zoneFilterUI,
                        extra: false
                    },
                    width: '120px',
                    template: '#=zone_name#'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Sales (native)',
                    headerTemplate: 'Sales <small>native</small>',
                    field: 'sales_total_native',
                    width: '110px',
                    template: '#=symbol+kendo.toString(sales_total_native, "n2")#'
                },
                {
                    title: 'VAT',
                    field: 'vat_native',
                    filterable: false,
                    sortable: false,
                    width: '80px',
                    template: '#=symbol+kendo.toString(vat_native, "n2")#',
                    footerTemplate: '#:  kendo.toString(sum, "n2") #<br /><span class="text-warning">#:  kendo.toString(average, "n2") #</span>'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Total',
                    field: 'sales_total',
                    filterable: false,
                    sortable: false,
                    width: '100px',
                    template: '#=symbol+kendo.toString(sales_total, "n2")#',
                    footerTemplate: '#:  kendo.toString(sum, "n2") #<br /><span class="text-warning">#:  kendo.toString(average, "n2") #</span>'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Margin',
                    field: 'margin',
                    width: '100px',
                    template: '<abbr title="#=kendo.toString(margin_percent, "p2")#">#=sales_symbol##=kendo.toString(margin, "n2")#</abbr>',
                    footerTemplate: '£#:  kendo.toString(sum, "n2") #<br /><span class="text-warning">£#:  kendo.toString(average, "n2") #</span>'
                },
                {
                    title: 'VAT #',
                    field: 'vatNumber',
                    width: '110px',
                    template: '#=vatNumber ? vatNumber : "<i class=\\"fa fa-pencil create-vat-number\\"></i>"#'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Total (£)',
                    field: 'sales_total_gdp',
                    width: '100px',
                    template: '<abbr title="Using an exchange rate of: #=rate#">#=sales_symbol##=kendo.toString(sales_total_gdp, "n2")#</abbr>',
                    footerTemplate: '#:  kendo.toString(sum, "n2") #<br /><span class="text-warning">#:  kendo.toString(average, "n2") #</span>'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Term',
                    field: 'term_id',
                    width: '90px',
                    filterable: {
                        ui: gridFunctions.paymentTermsFilterUI,
                        extra: false
                    },
                    template: '#=term#'
                },
                {
                    headerTemplate: 'Buying <small>parts</small>',
                    field: 'buying_parts_value_pounds',
                    width: '110px',
                    template: '#=sales_symbol##=kendo.toString(buying_parts_value_pounds, "n2")#',
                    footerTemplate: '#:  kendo.toString(sum, "n2") #<br /><span class="text-warning">#:  kendo.toString(average, "n2") #</span>'
                },
                {
                    headerTemplate: 'Buying <small>fees</small>',
                    field: 'buying_fees_value_pounds',
                    width: '100px',
                    template: '#=sales_symbol##=kendo.toString(buying_fees_value_pounds, "n2")#',
                    footerTemplate: '#:  kendo.toString(sum, "n2") #<br /><span class="text-warning">#:  kendo.toString(average, "n2") #</span>'
                },
                {
                    headerTemplate: 'Shipping',
                    field: 'shipping_value_pounds',
                    width: '90px',
                    template: '#=sales_symbol##=kendo.toString(shipping_value_pounds, "n2")#',
                    footerTemplate: '#:  kendo.toString(sum, "n2") #<br /><span class="text-warning">#:  kendo.toString(average, "n2") #</span>'
                },
                {
                    headerTemplate: 'Job costs',
                    field: 'job_costs_value_pounds',
                    width: '95px',
                    template: '#=sales_symbol##=kendo.toString(job_costs_value_pounds, "n2")#',
                    footerTemplate: '#:  kendo.toString(sum, "n2") #<br /><span class="text-warning">#:  kendo.toString(average, "n2") #</span>'
                },
                {
                    headerTemplate: 'Buying <small>total</small>',
                    field: 'buying_total',
                    width: '105px',
                    template: '#=sales_symbol##=kendo.toString(buying_total, "n2")#',
                    footerTemplate: '#:  kendo.toString(sum, "n2") #<br /><span class="text-warning">#:  kendo.toString(average, "n2") #</span>'
                },
                /*{
                 headerTemplate: 'Email invoices',
                 field: 'email_invoices',
                 filterable: {
                 ui: gridFunctions.yesNoFilterUI.bind(activeGrid),
                 extra: false
                 },
                 hidden: true,
                 width: '125px',
                 template: '#=email_invoices ? "Yes" : "No"#'
                 },*/
                {
                    headerTemplate: 'Print invoices',
                    field: 'print_invoices',
                    filterable: {
                        ui: gridFunctions.yesNoFilterUI.bind(activeGrid),
                        extra: false
                    },
                    hidden: true,
                    width: '125px',
                    template: '#=print_invoices ? "Yes" : "No"#'
                },
                {
                    headerTemplate: 'Invoice emailed',
                    field: 'emailed_date',
                    hidden: true,
                    width: '150px',
                    template: '#=emailed_date ? kendo.toString(emailed_date, "dd/MM/yyyy at HH:mm") : "-"#'
                },
                {
                    title: 'ZoneName',
                    field: 'zone_name',
                    hidden: true,
                    template: '#=zone_name#'
                },
            ],
            filterable: true,
            sortable: true,
            scrollable: true
        }).data("kendoGrid");
    }
```

But it keeps just exporting the "zone_id" and not the name, i.e. `14` should come out as `Italy`, but it doesn't, it comes out as `14`.

How do I get this to output the template content and not the raw values?

Comment: Does it work for all the other columns, except for zone?

Comment: @imperium2335 When Exporting as a excel the `footerTemplate` show the all html content. For example `<div style='white-space:initial;float:right'> $31,733.80</div>`